# How to get color components of a CGColor correctly

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics, cgcolor, cgcolorspace

I have a UILabel with black color;

i am writing the following code to get black color's components.

```
UIColor *aColor = [aLabel.textColor retain];
const CGFloat* components = CGColorGetComponents(aColor.CGColor);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace=CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
```

but always this is giving Green color components instead of black color components;

Is any one have idea about this?

Am i passing different color space?

:-(  Please help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most likely wrong colorspace. I guess the alpha component of the grayscale colorspace gets where you think the green component should be.
I use this function to create a string from UIColor, I only encounter RGB and Grayscale colorspaces, so I just interpret every color with less than 4 (R+G+B+A) components as grayscale.

```
if (CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(color.CGColor) < 4) {
    const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
    color = [UIColor colorWithRed:components[0] green:components[0] blue:components[0] alpha:components[1]];
}
if (CGColorSpaceGetModel(CGColorGetColorSpace(color.CGColor)) != kCGColorSpaceModelRGB) {
    NSLog(@"no rgb colorspace");
    // do seomthing
}
const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
NSString *colorAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f,%f,%f", components[0], components[1], components[2], components[3]];
```

of course this method is not save for all cases, you should adopt it to your requirements.

Comment: Hi fluchtpunkt! Thanks for your message! it helps me get some idea..can you tell me why it is giving r=0.000000 g=1.000000 b=0.000000 a=0.000000 when i am printing color components which are green color components even though i pass the black color. Thank you very much

Comment: I think the pointer that generated by CGColorGetComponents needs to be dealloced manually.

Comment: Nope. I was wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219370/where-is-the-memory-leak

Answer (score 7):

The reason you are seeing what looks like `r=0`, `g=1`, `b=0`, `a=0` is because you are misinterpreting the values in the returned array as being in an `RGB` color model. `UIColor` uses **monochrome colorspace** for **greyscale colors** like **black** in this case.
What you are seeing is an array of `2` components from a **monochrome color model**. The first is **gray level** (`0` for black) and the second is **alpha** (`1` for opaque).  The last two values your are looking at are off the end of the `2` element array and happen to be `0` in this case.

You'll notice if color is black and you try `CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(color.CGColor)`, it returns `2`. And if you try `CGColorSpaceGetModel(CGColorGetColorSpace(color.CGColor))`, it returns `0` which corresponds to `kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome` (see the enum `CGColorSpaceModel` in `CGColorSpace.h`)

see [CGColorSpace Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGColorSpace/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGColorSpaceModel)

Comment: thanks, now I got it. it doesn't hurt if they unify both grayscale and non-grayscale to 4 components, since grayscale can also be represented by RGB. I am surprised to find iOS has distinguished those two and not even document this :P

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a very nice way to get the rgb representation of any UIColor*, which already has a convenience method for retaining it´s components.

```
-(CGColorRef)CGColorRefFromUIColor:(UIColor*)newColor {
     CGFloat components[4] = {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};
     [newColor getRed:&components[0] green:&components[1] blue:&components[2]        alpha:&components[3]];
     CGColorRef newRGB = CGColorCreate(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), components);
     return newRGB;
}
```

Comment: Beware! iOS5+ only. Also, you're not releasing the colorspace object you created.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get RGB for these is by drawing the color into a graphics context and reading the color back out. See my answer to this question for example code:

[Get RGB value from UIColor presets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700168/get-rgb-value-from-uicolor-presets)

Answer (score 0):

working exampel with UIColor: 
`CALayer * btnLayer = [myLittleButton layer];`

`[layer setBackgroundColor:<#(CGColorRef)#>]` becomes: `[btnLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];`

just make sure the buttons original colors doesnt cover the layer

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UIColor {

  func toRGB() -> UIColor? {
    guard let model = cgColor.colorSpace?.model else {
      return nil
    }
    
    let components = cgColor.components

    switch model {
    case .rgb:
      return UIColor(red: components?[0] ?? 0.0, green: components?[1] ?? 0.0, blue: components?[2] ?? 0.0, alpha: components?[3] ?? 0.0)
    case .monochrome:
      return UIColor(red: components?[0] ?? 0.0, green: components?[0] ?? 0.0, blue: components?[0] ?? 0.0, alpha: components?[1] ?? 0.0)
    default:
      return nil
    }
  }
}
```