# ios Convert integer color to uicolor or hex values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, hex, uicolor

In android there is an option where you can set color based on int value. Is there anyway that I can use this value or convert this value to set it as `UIColor` in iOS? 
For example this value, `-5242884` can be used in android to set color.

From what I managed to find is that iOS widely use hex value or rgb value to set for `UIColor`. But I couldn't find any info regarding about my issue here. Is there anyway around that I can use int value instead.

Comment: What does the negative integer represent?

Comment: It's actually a color value which can set at android side. In android I can convert that negative integer value into hex value. But I wanted to know whether I can convert that value in iOS or not.

Comment: int type has 4 byte, Does first byte stands for red value, second->green value, third->blue value, last->alpha ?

Comment: @KudoCC To be frank, I'm not really sure what that int value stands for. I'm a bit clueless about all these myself.

Comment: I think you should know which the color space is it. If it is using RGB, you still need to care ARGB and RGBA.

Comment: It makes no sense to have a negative value.

Comment: @rmaddy I agreed. Cause I too see no sense of it. But you can test it on android, I don't know why negative value works but it just works.

Comment: How can I test it Android? There is no context. What algorithm is used to convert the negative value to RGB?

Comment: Just test it out this way. Set it to a view. It accepts int value. For example, `view.setBackgroundColor(color)` Define `color` as the value above.

Comment: See my updated answer below. I think it answers your question now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears that the integer number to which you are referencing is a packed integer. See: [android color documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html). You need to find a way to convert the packed int to a hex and then you can use this macro (obtained [here](http://aralbalkan.com/2252)) which converts a hex number to UIColor:

```
#define HEXCOLOR(c) [UIColor colorWithRed:((c>>24)&0xFF)/255.0 green:((c>>16)&0xFF)/255.0 blue:((c>>8)&0xFF)/255.0  alpha:((c)&0xFF)/255.0]
```

I know this doesn't really answer your question but it may help you narrow down your search.

**Edit**

Ok so I just realized the above macro does solve your problem. Just give it the integer representation and it will give you the right UIColor. My test code is below:

```
UIColor *color = HEXCOLOR(-16776961); // Blue const from android link above
const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
NSString *colorAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f,%f,%f", components[0], components[1], components[2], components[3]]; 
NSLog(@"%@",colorAsString); // Prints 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 which corresponds to 0xff0000ff
```

I had some help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155642/how-to-get-color-components-of-a-cgcolor-correctly).

**Edit**

Fixed the macro to expect the correct RGBA values:

```
#define ANDROID_COLOR(c) [UIColor colorWithRed:((c>>16)&0xFF)/255.0 green:((c>>8)&0xFF)/255.0 blue:((c)&0xFF)/255.0  alpha:((c>>24)&0xFF)/255.0]
```

The previous macro expected RGBA while the Android color int gave ARGB.

Comment: `UIColor *color = HEXCOLOR(-16776961);` The value in `color` returns as blue in android, but it appears as red in iOS. =( Somehow the marco worked but lack of accuracy.

Comment: @IssacZH. I think it has to do with the order of the RGBA values. The Android color is probably ARGB while the UIColor is RGBA so basically red and blue would have been switched in the example. Modify the macro to put them in the correct order. I'll post an edit to my answer.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much the color now is matched with android. You're a lifesaver. =) If it's not too much, may I ask is it possible to convert it the other way around from hex or rgb value?

Comment: I've not worked with it that way but I'd assume its possible. Try reverse engineering the macro. Start with the color components in hex then bit shift the other way (<<) and OR them together. Good luck. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Swift version if it helps anyone:

```
func getUIColorFromAndroidColorInt(androidColorInt: Int) -> UIColor {

        let red = (CGFloat) ( (androidColorInt>>16)&0xFF )
        let green = (CGFloat) ( (androidColorInt>>8)&0xFF )
        let blue = (CGFloat) ( (androidColorInt)&0xFF )

        return UIColor(red: red/255, green: green/255, blue: blue/255, alpha: 1)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension for UIColor in Swift that adds convenience methods to initialize a color from an Android packed ColorInt value and retrieve the ColorInt value from a UIColor instance.

```swift
/**
 An extension to `UIColor` that provides convenience methods for working with Android packed ColorInt values.
 */
extension UIColor {
    /**
     Initializes a `UIColor` instance with the specified Android packed ColorInt value.
     
     - Parameter colorInt: The Android packed ColorInt value.
     - Returns: A new `UIColor` instance.
     
     - Note: The `colorInt` value should be a 32-bit integer representing a color in ARGB format.
     */
    convenience init(colorInt: Int32) {
        let alpha = (colorInt >> 24) & 0xFF
        let red = (colorInt >> 16) & 0xFF
        let green = (colorInt >> 8) & 0xFF
        let blue = colorInt & 0xFF
        self.init(red: CGFloat(red) / 255.0,
                  green: CGFloat(green) / 255.0,
                  blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255.0,
                  alpha: CGFloat(alpha) / 255.0)
    }

    /**
     Retrieves the Android packed ColorInt value of the `UIColor` instance.
     
     - Returns: The Android packed ColorInt value.
     
     - Note: The returned value is a 32-bit integer representing the color in ARGB format.
     */
    var colorInt: Int32 {
        let components = cgColor.components ?? [0, 0, 0, 0]
        let red = components[0] * 255
        let green = components[1] * 255
        let blue = components[2] * 255
        let alpha = components[3] * 255
        return Int32(alpha) << 24 | Int32(red) << 16 | Int32(green) << 8 | Int32(blue)
    }
}
```

With this extension, you can easily create a UIColor instance from an Android packed ColorInt value using the UIColor(colorInt:) initializer. Additionally, you can retrieve the Android packed ColorInt value from a UIColor instance using the colorInt property.

Example usage:

```swift
let packedColor: Int32 = -16776961
let color = UIColor(colorInt: packedColor)
print(color) // Output: UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 1 1

let extractedColorInt = color.colorInt
print(extractedColorInt) // Output: -16776961
```

In the example above, the UIColor instance color is created from the packed color int value -16776961, representing a blue color. The extracted ColorInt value extractedColorInt is then printed, which matches the original packed color int value.

Comment: This code will crash in many cases. For example: `print(UIColor.white.colorInt)`. Not all colors are RGBA and not all colors have 4 components.